# useState set value cannot update immediately

Tags: use-state

I want to change to the value of one useState item then set item to AsyncStorage,
but I found that the value of useState is still kept previous value and then saved to AsyncStorage.
Please help what can I do ? Many Thanks

below is my sample code:

```
 const [myGetNo,setMyGetNo] = useState(0)

  useEffect(()=>{        
        console.log('useEffect ',myGetNo)
    },[myGetNo])    

 _storeData =async  () => {
        try {
             setMyGetNo(2)  
             let myTicket ={myGetNo:myGetNo}
             await AsyncStorage.setItem('myTicket',JSON.stringify(myTicket))
            }            
        } catch (err) {
         console.log('AsyncStorage SetItem Error: ',err) 
        }
     };
```

As a result:
the value of myGetNo is still initial value 0 , not 2 , saved in AsyncStorage.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [useState set method not reflecting change immediately](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54069253/usestate-set-method-not-reflecting-change-immediately)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/54069332/5349104 refer this answer. This is already answered here.

Answer (score 0):

The value of state `myGetNo` is only updated after rerendering. So in the `try` and `catch` blocks, the AsyncStorage is using the old myGetNo value.

To solve this, update the `try` block like this:

```
const newNo = myGetNo + 2
setMyGetNo(newNo)  
let myTicket ={myGetNo: newNo}
await AsyncStorage.setItem('myTicket',JSON.stringify(myTicket))
```